# Get textfield.text from tableview

Tags: iphone, uitextfield

I have table view with UIButton , UILable and UITextfield
I have wrote in cellForRowAtIndexPath:

UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

```
cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

[cell addSubview:button];    
[cell addSubview:lable];
[cell addSubview:textfield];
```

I have set the text on lable and textfield are working properly. 
When i change the text on textfield are also working properly.

And i have other button for save data - it's a out side of tableview but in the same view.

My Question is when i click save button i want to get text of tableview's textfield.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want the text in every text field or a single row's?

Also, the code you use to create your table view cells isn't doing what you want it to do. First you are trying to dequeue a reusable cell, which is great. But you then immediately overwrite that reused cell by alloc/initing a brand new cell every time. Only if cell == nil should you alloc/init a new one.

Answer (score 1):

If you have one or two textfields create it in the IB but outside the currentview, hook to outlet, then use the outlet to save the text .this is not a good idea if your table view containing many rows, in that case consider creating custom cell

[Check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1839772/textfield-in-uitableview)

Answer (score 0):

All of the textFields? I would recommend adding the textFields to a mutableArray as they are created, creating another mutableArray to store the textField text, then on button push, calling:

```
for(UITextField *textField in myArray){ [myTextArray addObject:textField.text];}
```

Then you could save the array, or whatever.  If there's only one textField, how you access it will depend where it's declared, etc.